# Xamarin Forms Custom progress bar blurred

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I´m using a custom renderer to customize the height and color of my progress bar, but my progress bar gets blurred:

[image]

My CustomRenderer looks like this:

```
public class ColorProgressBarRenderer : ProgressBarRenderer
{
    public ColorProgressBarRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.ProgressBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Control != null)
        {
            UpdateBarColor();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == ColorProgressBar.BarColorProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateBarColor();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateBarColor()
    {
        var element = Element as ColorProgressBar;

        Control.ProgressTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(element.BarColor.ToAndroid());
        Control.ScaleY = 10f;
    }
}
```

My CustomProgressBar looks like this:

```
public class ColorProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    //public static BindableProperty BarColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ColorProgressBar, Color>(p => p.BarColor, default(Color));
    public static BindableProperty BarColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BarColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ColorProgressBar), default(Color));

    public Color BarColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BarColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This only happens in Android, with my iOS Renderer all is working fine!
Why this is happen?

Comment: could you show your axml which use CustomProgressBar ,it not  blurred,but I think it's  maybe the result of ScaleY increasing the height

Comment: and what your device version ？

Comment: I guess we'll never know...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this advanced progress bar.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MultiColor.ProgressBar/
Documentation: https://github.com/udayaugustin/ProgressBar/blob/master/README.md

It supports multi color.
It has properties like

- Height
- Width
- Corner Radius and etc